# How to parameterized request if getting recorded script like this.? See details

Tags: jmeter

How to parameterize request if I am getting something similar to the following for `login POST request` in body data tab.

```
"{\"msg\":\"method\",\"method\":\"login\",\"params\":[{\"user\":{\"username\":\"testuser\"},\"password\":{\"digest\":\"5811c74a581ffdb892ab9eddfb9cf2d21772a98332a59de6aa26989e01f84057\",\"algorithm\":\"sha-256\"}}],\"id\":\"7\"}"]
```

It's generally easy to correlate when we are getting in Parameters TAB, but in cases how we can proceed? For all further requests - it's the similar case. 
I tried to switch to Parameters TAB, but it says that it can not be converted to that format.

So How we can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The same way, just substitute hard-coded (recorded) values with the relevant [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) directly in the request body like:

> "{\"msg\":\"method\",\"method\":\"login\",\"params\":[{\"user\":{\"username\":\"**${username}**\"},\"password\":{\"digest\":\"**${password}**\",\"algorithm\":\"sha-256\"}}],\"id\":\"**${id}**\"}"]

The most commonly used for parameterization test element is [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG), however other options exist.